# separate key value from facebook token array

Tags: php, arrays, phalcon

I'm trying to access `facebook login` without `sdk` with `php` that's why I get access_token from `facebook` like below:

```
array(1) { ["{"access_token":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":543543581}"]=> string(0) "" }
```

but i want only `access_token => "xxxxxxxxxxx"` like this `$access_token['access_token'];`

i already try like :

```
    if(isset($access_token['access_token']) || array_key_exists('access_token', $access_token))
```

or
     parse_str($access_token, $token_array);

but no luck!!

How could I do this?

```
public function facebookAction()
{
    if(isset($_REQUEST["error"]))
    {
        $this->flashSession->error("ERROR:: ".$_REQUEST['error']);
        return $this->response->redirect('index');             
    }
    elseif(isset($_REQUEST["code"]))
    {
        if(isset($_REQUEST["state"]) && $_REQUEST["state"]==$_SESSION["state"])
        {
            $access_token = $this->get_access_token();
//[ Problem is here ] 
            $raw = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,email,picture,gender&access_token=".$access_token);


            $data_array = json_decode($raw,TRUE);
            $fbid = $data_array['id'];
            $fbmail = $data_array['email'];
            $this->session->set('id', '1000');
            $this->session->set("uname", $fbmail);
            $this->flashSession->success("SUCCESS:: You are now flying with Phalcon!");
                return $this->response->redirect('index');
        }else{ $this->flashSession->error("ERROR:: Request STATE & CODE Error!");return $this->response->redirect('index'); }
    }else{ $this->dialog(); }
}    

function generate_state(){ return md5(uniqid(rand(),TRUE)); }

function dialog(){
    $app_secret = "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb";
    $app_id = "aaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    //$auth_type = 'rerequest';
    $redirect_uri = urlencode("https://localhost/firefly/Oauth/facebook"); 
    $fbPermission = array('email');
    $defaultGraphVersion = 'v3.2';
    $state = $this->generate_state();
    $_SESSION["state"] = $state;
    return $this->response->redirect('https://www.facebook.com/'.$defaultGraphVersion.'/dialog/oauth?client_id='.$app_id.'&scope=email&redirect_uri='.$redirect_uri.'&state='.$state);
}
function get_access_token(){
    $app_secret = "bbbbbbbbbbbbb";
    $app_id = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    $redirect_uri = urlencode("https://localhost/firefly/Oauth/facebook"); 
    $code = $_REQUEST["code"];
    $response = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=".$app_id."&redirect_uri=".$redirect_uri."&client_secret=".$app_secret."&code=".$code);
    json_decode($response, $access_token);
    return $access_token;
}
```

Comment: How are you creating the array? The array element is an array containing a JSON string, not a decoded object.

Comment: It's even weirder. The JSON string is the key of an associative array.

Comment: You need to show the code that's creating `$access_token`, you have some problems there.

Comment: I updated my code!! if i add "file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,email,picture,gender&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");" like this its working perfectly but i need $access_token['access_token']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in `get_access_token` change `parse_str` to `json_decode`;

```
parse_str('{"access_token":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":543543581}', $res);

print_r($res);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [{"access_token":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":543543581}] => 
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/73db9f7198b77132a026723a5649d2fbdee0c18f)

Parse string just takes the string and treats it like this, similar to if it was part of a URL query string `example.com?foo`:

```
parse_str('foo=bar', $res);
print_r($res);

parse_str('foo', $res);
print_r($res);
```

Output

```
//parse_str('foo=bar', $res);
Array
(
    [foo] => bar
)
//parse_str('foo', $res);
Array
(
    [foo] => 
)
```

And just as `foo` would become the key in `[foo => bar]` your string become the key up there.

> **parse_str**  Parses encoded_string as if it were the query string passed via a URL and sets variables in the current scope (or in the array if result is provided).

Using Json Decode

```
print_r(json_decode('{"access_token":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":543543581}', true));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [access_token] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [token_type] => bearer
    [expires_in] => 543543581
)
```

So:

```
 function get_access_token(){
    $app_secret = "bbbbbbbbbbbbb";
    $app_id = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    $redirect_uri = urlencode("https://localhost/firefly/Oauth/facebook"); 
    $code = $_REQUEST["code"];
    $response = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=".$app_id."&redirect_uri=".$redirect_uri."&client_secret=".$app_secret."&code=".$code);
    $res = json_decode($response, true);

     //return false or the access_token
    return isset($res['access_token']) ? $res['access_token'] : false;
     //OR
    return $res;  //return the whole response

     //---------- old code ---------
    //parse_str($response, $access_token);
    //return $access_token;
}
```

Comment: updated as your instruction. i just get "xxxxxxxxxx" value by: foreach ($access_token as $key => $value) {echo "$key = $value<br/>";} and then i manually copy the value but not working with $access_token

Comment: You only have one access token, `$access_token['access_token']` or you can just return that from `get_access_token`

Comment: Thanx So Much!! Gr8 Job my Friend!! It's Working as expected.

Comment: Kool, it was pretty obvious when I saw `parse_str` as that is used for query string data not JSON.

Answer (score 2):

So you are getting response as array item, where key is your JSON data and empty value?

Your response is ugly, but this is how you would have grabbed your value:

```
<?php
    $response = [
        '{"access_token":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":543543581}' => '',
    ];

    $response_key = \array_keys($response)[0];
    $response_array = \json_decode($response_key, true);
    $access_token = $response_array['access_token'];

    echo $access_token;
?>
```